# Form with self-referencing data (Symfony 5)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm doing an app with Symfony 5 and there is a problem i don't manage to find a solution, I have no idea.

I want to make a form of an entity "Person".
A Person can add in his family other Person.

So in my entity I made a Many-To-Many self referencing to Person.

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $birthdaydate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $gender;

    /** 
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Person")
     * @JoinTable(name="family",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person__id", referencedColumnName="person__id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="family_id", referencedColumnName="person__id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $myFamily;
```

And now, I want to make a form in which I can add new Person, in a person.
I did a CollectionType, like symfony said, but when i want to print it to the page, I get a timeout because of an infinite loop.

It's the "allow_add" which causes the problem.

And i need the prototype variable returned by "allow_add" to add new field in the front.

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class,  ['attr' => ['class' => 'form_textfield']])
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('birthdayDate', TextType::class,  ['attr' => ['class' => 'form_datetime']])
            ->add('gender', GenderType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
            ->add('myFamily', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => PersonType::class, 'mapped' => false, 'allow_add' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'allow_delete' => true));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Person::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is my form, but there is nothing interesting, I will add the js necessary when i will be resolve this problem.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello PersonController!
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    {{ form_row(form.firstname) }}
    {{ form_row(form.birthdayDate) }}
    {{ form_row(form.gender) }}
{{ form_row(form.myFamily) }}
    <button type="button" class="add_item_link" data-collection-holder-class="tags">Add a tag</but
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Dylan Kas was good, just by adding a new form, it's good.

The Person Form

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class,  ['attr' => ['class' => 'form_textfield']])
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('birthdayDate', TextType::class,  ['attr' => ['class' => 'form_datetime']])
            ->add('gender', GenderType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
            ->add('myFamily', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => ChildType::class, 'by_reference' => false, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Person::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The child, referenced by myFamily :

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class,  ['attr' => ['class' => 'form_textfield']])
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('birthdayDate', TextType::class,  ['attr' => ['class' => 'form_datetime']])
            ->add('gender', GenderType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Person::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the view :

```
{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    {{ form_row(form.firstname) }}
    {{ form_row(form.birthdayDate) }}
    {{ form_row(form.gender) }}
    <button type="button" class="add_item_link" data-collection-holder-class="myFamily">Add a tag</button>
    <ul class="myFamily" data-index="{{ form.myFamily|length > 0 ? form.myFamily|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.myFamily.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"></ul>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

With the js associated

```
const addFormToCollection = (e) => {
  const collectionHolder = document.querySelector(
    "." + e.currentTarget.dataset.collectionHolderClass
  );

  const item = document.createElement("li");

  item.innerHTML = collectionHolder.dataset.prototype.replace(
    /__name__/g,
    collectionHolder.dataset.index
  );

  collectionHolder.appendChild(item);

  collectionHolder.dataset.index++;
};

document
  .querySelectorAll(".add_item_link")
  .forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener("click", addFormToCollection));
```

It still need some work, maybe I can make the child form extending the person form. The front need some work too. But the next people facing this problem will have the solution here.

I am still asking myself how could I do if I've needed to have a form including itself the same form, including itself the same form etc...
The form would be recursivable.

Comment: saved me nearly 3 hours of trying. Did it too with a ChildForm.

Answer (score 0):

There is an infinite loop because the myFamily property references a Person entity which itself references a myFamily property ...

To keep things simple, one way to manage the family of a person would be to create a separate Family entity.
From the Person point of view, it seems more coherent to have a ManyToOne relationship with a family.
After that, you can add the family of a Person by using the EntityType:class inside the PersonFormType.

Here is the documentation for EntityType : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: Creating another entity is not necessary. However, using the same `PersonType` in your collection type is an issue. You could either use another type or simply use groups to have a collection of PersonType without myFamily.

Comment: @Parian, In the case of I would make a new entity "Family", I would like to click on an add button and then get the form of the Family entity. 

But it's not possible to do that with an EntityType right ? 

And Dylan Kas, can you link me the doc of "groups", I don't see what you are talking about

Comment: @Arkandas, yes you're right EntityType is just a field to choose the related entity. If you want to combine Person form and Family form, you can use embedded form : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html. Another way is to create a model class that fit your form (and you will bind it with the data_class option) and you use it to transfer data to the right entities

Comment: Yes, that's why I did a collection class in first place. But with one entity, and only one form it doesn't work haha.

I didn't see the data_class option, i will look at in later but i don't think I will use it.

Thanks both for your answers, it helps me a lot.